# Why does Windows 10 freeze for no reason?

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, crash

I've come across something strange with my PC rig running Windows 10.

Out of the blue, it seems to just lock up and freeze after using it for a bit. However this doesn't happen all the time, just the odd occasion. I'm not using anything CPU heavy or anything like that, just Google Chrome and Word. I have to press the power button to un freeze it.

I've tried a variety of options through researching online, updated my display drivers, installed latest updates for windows, DISM, chkdsk, sfc /scannow, virus scans, all come back fine with nothing to report.

I had a look at the reliability history, and there has a been a few times where there is a log that is a Windows Hardware Error, which is strange as I've not changed hardware in the last year or so, and this problem has been happening for about a week.

This is what the RH says:
[image]

And I have no idea what this means, can anyone hazard a guess or give me an idea what this error means? Thanks :-)

Comment: do you need to reboot to unfreeze or just waiting do the trick?

Comment: Yes I have to manually reboot using the power button

Comment: win32k.sys = graphic system. so update the GPU drivers and look what happens

Comment: @magicandre1981 they are updated to their latest and it still crashes

Comment: @Tom 1) Can you revert the video drivers to an earlier version? 2) [One user](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/a-problem-with-your-hardware-caused-windows-to/62988809-06e1-42fc-9a92-154cc5c49b75) reported that "uninstall the cumulative update KB3197954" worked for them.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The freezing occurs both before and after changing my videwo drivers, so I don't think that is the issue. Your second option I read through, and from that thread it looks like this could be a Microsoft bug?

Comment: @Tom Does it only go wrong when you are using Chrome? You could try using Edge (I know...) instead just to see if Chrome is a contributing factor. As you change the hardware yourself, I assume you have made sure there are no dust bunnies causing anything to overheat. If you're using a graphics card, what model is it? And what model of PSU does it have?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Unfortunetaly not it freezes sometimes when not using chrome. Nothing could overheat, no dust. I've got an nVidia GTX 760.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the HDD health? Usually when a Laptop is having slowdowns or random freezes it means, in my experience, that the HDD is having problems, like physical problems. Try cloning the drive and then booting it, if it doesn't freeze then swaping a fresh drive in might do the trick.

Am i right to suposse that your pc is a laptop and not a rig?

Comment: Sorry, I have a rig, I'll update my question.

Comment: Anyway, check your drives health. It's possible that they are indeed damaged by some bump, heat, electric, etc.